# Detecting Extensions enabled in Firefox using JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there anyway that we can find out the extensions that are enabled and disabled in firefox using Javascript or PHP script?

I need to alert a message if the extension is enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would probably depend on the extension and what it does.

Comment: PHP will be of no use to you here.

Comment: what extension specifically?

Comment: One or two extensions might do something like set headers when visiting websites, but in general no, only the browser application (or other extensions) has access to this data. You could write an extension to make the data available to your website, of course `:)`.

Comment: @andrew I need to detect whether YSlow has been installed or not..!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the extension.

Some extensions actually modify the html/dom of your page so you can easily identify them.

like InFormEnter:
This extension creates img elements which you can identify using jquery:

```
if ($("img.ife_marker").length > 0) alert("InformEnter installed!");
```

But only a few do this, and you can only guess the behaviour (or fork the extension to add something like this).

IF you have an extension that has such a behaviour (you can create a test-page and use firebug to search the dom tree for added/changed elements) then you could write some javascript (like the example above) and use JSON to send the information back to your server.

Some extensions might react to requests you send out (like modify headers) - then you can create an ajax request with a know header and check this.

The only reason I could theoretically think of when this makes any sense would be in a closed office environment where you want to check for specific addons that have to be installed in order for your app to work. 
In that case I would actually create a fork of the extension and make it append such a marker to the page.

Edit: since you mention yslow:
No yslow does not do ANYTHING to the page. It actually only takes information already available within firefox and analyzes the page based on that. It does not even create any extra http requests which you could theoretically pick up on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can test this scripts :

- https://github.com/geedew/browser-detect
- https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr

Comment: HI.. thanks for this.. this JS works only for plugins not for extensions.. :( :( :(